# duplicate object is being appended in array swift firebase

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am populating a UITableView with firebase data.

I have been using the same process to create multiple tableviews in the same way (I'm copying and pasting previous code and amending it as necessary), so I'm sure enough that it works.

in this case though, I'm having issues with the tableview's array for which the cells are populated.

Though I can see that my firebase query block is pulling two distinct sets of data, when I tell it to append each object (in this case titled a Round()), it is appending only the 1st one, as many times as there are objects. here's my code:

```
let cellId = "cellId"
var roundArray = [Round]()
let activeCourse = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "activeCourse")
let ref = Database.database().reference()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style:.plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleBack))
    navigationItem.title = "Choose Round to Review"

    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let round = Round()

    let UID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    ref.child("userRoundData").child(UID).queryOrdered(byChild: "RoundScore").observe( .childAdded, with: { snapshot in

        if let value = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

            round.name = value["RoundName"] as! String?
            round.date = value["RoundDate"] as! String?
            round.score = value["RoundScore"] as! Int?
            round.putts = value["RoundPutts"] as! Int?
            round.tees = value["RoundTees"] as! String?
            round.FIR = value["roundFIR"] as! Int?
            round.GIR = value["roundGIR"] as! Int?
            round.is9or18 = value["Round9or18"] as! String?
            round.possibleFIR = value["roundPossibleFIR"] as! Int?
            round.course = value["RoundCourse"] as! String?


            if round.is9or18 == "Eighteen" {
                round.possibleGIR = 18
            } else {
                round.possibleGIR = 9
            }

            round.FIRPercentage = (Float(round.FIR!) / Float(round.possibleFIR!))
            round.GIRPercentage = (Float(round.GIR!) / Float(round.possibleGIR!))

            print(round.name!)
            print(round)
            self.roundArray.append(round)
            print(self.roundArray)

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            })
        }
    })

    self.ref.removeAllObservers()


}
```

and here are the printouts in my console. it shows that there are two entries for round.name, but when I append, you can see that the two objects that end up appended are the same.

```
 Round played at Eagle Trace Golf Club  07-16-2017 from Gold tees
<NoteCaddieNotes.Round: 0x7f9ec8016400>
[<NoteCaddieNotes.Round: 0x7f9ec8016400>]
Round played at Riverdale Golf Course - Dunes  07-13-2017 from Gold tees
<NoteCaddieNotes.Round: 0x7f9ec8016400>
[<NoteCaddieNotes.Round: 0x7f9ec8016400>, <NoteCaddieNotes.Round: 0x7f9ec8016400>]
```

my question is.... WHY?!?!?! hahaha it's been very frustrating, and I'm not sure what else to do. I may add this is my first project in swift, heck in coding in general. so it may be something obvious that I'm just not understanding completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it because your creation of the Round object is happening only once at ViewWillAppear and not at the time when you are adding the values to that object?

```
let round = Round()
```

This line should be a part of your observe closure after

```
if let value = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]
```

Sorry would have added as a comment but don't have commenting rights yet.

Comment: Its My pleasure :)